The algebraic K-group of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1 \bigcup T_{\Delta\mathbb{P}^1}^*(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1)$
Let $\mathbb{P}^1=\mathbb{P}^1(\mathbb{C})$, $Z_1=T_{\Delta\mathbb{P}^1}^*(\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1)$ is the conormal bundle of $\Delta\mathbb{P}^1$ in $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, $Z_2=\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, $Z=Z_1 \bigcup Z_2$, the canonical closed immersion $i_1, i_2$. The $K(Z)$ is defined by the Grothendieck group of the category of coherent sheaves on $Z$.
Now let me explain the structure sheaves of the above varieties. The structure sheaf of $Z$ is isomorphic to the algebra sheaf $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}_n t^n$ where $\mathcal{L}_0=\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}, \mathcal{L}_n=\mathcal{O}_{\Delta\mathbb{P}^1}(2n)t^n$ for $n>0$, the structure sheaf of $Z_1$ is isomorphic to the algebra sheaf $\bigoplus_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{O}_{\Delta\mathbb{P}^1}(2n)t^n)$ and the structure sheaf of $Z_2$ is isomorphic to the algebra sheaf $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1}$.
Then $\mathrm{Ker}(\mathcal{O}_Z \rightarrow i_{2*}\mathcal{O}_{Z_2})=\bigoplus_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{O}_{\Delta\mathbb{P}^1}(2n)t^n=\mathcal{O}_{Z_1}(2)t$, $\mathrm{Ker}(\mathcal{O}_Z \rightarrow i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{Z_1})=\mathrm{Ker}(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\Delta\mathbb{P}^1})=\mathcal{O}_{Z_2}(-1,-1)$.
So we have the exact sequences
$$0 \rightarrow i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{Z_1}(2) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z \rightarrow i_{2*}\mathcal{O}_{Z_2} \rightarrow 0,$$
$$0 \rightarrow i_{2*}\mathcal{O}_{Z_2}(-1,-1) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z \rightarrow i_{1*}\mathcal{O}_{Z_1} \rightarrow 0.$$
Then by shifting the down sequence by $(1,1)$, we can obtain
$$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Z_2} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_Z(1,1) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}_{Z_1}(2) \rightarrow 0.$$
Therefore, $\mathcal{O}_Z(1,1)=\mathcal{O}_{Z_2}+\mathcal{O}_{Z_1}(2)=\mathcal{O}_Z$ in $K(Z)$?! But the pull-backs of $\mathcal{O}_Z$ and $\mathcal{O}_Z(1,1)$ on $Z_1$ or $Z_2$ are different clearly. So where is the mistake? Is there a mistake in the exact sequences?

It is not a good idea to post the same question on MO and SE simultaneously.

Ok, I am new here. Let's just talk here, I will delete on the other. As I have added, their pull-backs aren't the same, so there should be some contradiction?

Contradiction with what?

$\mathcal{O}_Z=\mathcal{O}Z(1,1)$ but $i_2^{*}(\mathcal{O}Z)=\mathcal{O}{Z_2} \neq \mathcal{O}{Z_2}(1,1) = i_2^{}(\mathcal{O}_Z(1,1))$. $i^$ is the derived pull-back, but it is just the pull back in the case of vector bundle.

I am not asking about this, my question is what does this contradict?

$\mathcal{O}Z=\mathcal{O}Z(1,1)$ contradicts $\mathcal{O}{Z_2} \neq \mathcal{O}{Z_2}(1,1)$.

So, what is your reason to think that the equality holds?

By shifting the down sequence by $(1,1)$, then we obtain $$0 \rightarrow \mathcal{O}{Z_2} \rightarrow \mathcal{O}Z(1,1) \rightarrow \mathcal{O}{Z_1}(2) \rightarrow 0.$$
Therefore, $\mathcal{O}Z(1,1)=\mathcal{O}{Z_2}+\mathcal{O}{Z_1}(2)=\mathcal{O}_Z$.

That should be explained in the question. You should also clarify what exactly do you mean by $K(Z)$ --- there are different versions and since your $Z$ is not smooth, the precise definition matters.

Thank you. I have modified the statement as your suggestion.

As I said, you should also clarify what do you mean by $K(Z)$.

The problem is that $i_1^*$ or $i_2^*$ isn't well-defined between Grothendieck groups. Because the derived functors $i_1^*$ and $i_2^*$ aren't homologically finite.
